# Part of fragment covered by AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this issue: Part of my fragments in ViewPager are covered by AppBarLayout in container layout. In following example, my textview is hidden underneath the tabs.

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95Aka.jpg)

**Container:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="pl.webtube.pracainzynierska.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

tools:context="pl.webtube.pracainzynierska.OneFragment">



<TextView
    android:layout_below="@id/appBarLayout"
    android:text="Sample text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Here I populate fragments inside ViewPager:

```
 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "ONE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I've tried `android:layout_below` with AppBarLayout, but it makes no difference.

What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use linear layout instead...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="pl.webtube.pracainzynierska.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</LinearLayout >
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code from

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

to this...add **android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"** this line in your ViewPager tag

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"/>
```